Let $a, b, c$ be the roots of the cubic equation $z^3+Az^2 +Bz+8=0$, where $A$ and $B$ are real. Find $A$ and $B$
Let $a, b, c$ be the roots of the cubic equation $z^3+Az^2 +Bz+8=0$, where $A$ and $B$ are real. Furthermore $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ and $b^2+c^2=0$. Now, $b$ is real, while $a$ and $c$ are purely imaginary.
Find $A$ and $B$.
UPDATE: SOLVED FROM COMMENTS
What I TRIED:
$$\begin{align}
a+b+c &= -A \qquad \text{(sum of roots)} \tag{1} \\
ab+bc+ca &= B \qquad \text{(sum of roots two at a time)}\tag{2} \\
abc &= -8 \qquad \text{(product of roots)}\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
But the cubic has real coefficients, so $a$ and $c$ are complex conjugates (they are purely imaginary roots, as stated above)
Hence $a=-c$, which, if we substitute into the equations $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ yields
$(1) \implies b=-A$
$(2) \implies -a^2=B$
$(3) \implies -a^2b=-8$
So: $$B(-A)=-8 \qquad \text{and} \qquad BA = 8.$$
Now, the answer is $B = 4, \, A=2$. This would have been easy to deduce if only the question told me that $B$ and $A$ were integers and both positive. How do I deduce these conditions?
Thank you!

It seems to me that you are not using the two conditions $a^2 + b^2 =0$ and $b^2 + c^2 =0$. Moreover, there is a typo: "from $1$. $b=-A$".

From $a^2 + b^2 = b^2 + c^2 = 0$ and $b$ real,  follows $a = bi, c = -bi$, so we obtain $(x - bi)(x + bi)(x - b) = (x^2 + b^2)(x - b) = x^3 - bx^2 + b^2x - b^3$, hence $b = -2, B = 4, A = 2$.

@Ronald Why not an official answer?

@PaulFrost very often my answers are classified as not rigorous enough (in the comments that follow). I often delete such answers because they apparently have no value. Hence just a comment as a hint and the task to make it rigorous left to the OP. I make exceptions if the comment would be too long.

@Ronald, it you want to give a hint as an answer, that is fine, Just start it out with "Hint:". Don't take what is said in comments too deep to heart. While some who visit this forum are hypercritical, the large majority of the criticism you receive is actually from people who want to assist you in clarifying your post, at least have a mutually beneficial dialog. In this case, your comment is a full answer, not a hint, and is quite rigorous (leaving only very basic algebra unsaid), so would be better offered as answer, as then the question shows up as answered.

From $a^2+b^2=b^2+c^2=0$ and $b$ real, follows $a=bi,c=−bi$, so we obtain $(x−bi)(x+bi)(x−b)=(x^2+b^2)(x−b)=x^3−bx^2+b^2x−b^3$, hence $b=−2,B=4,A=2$.
The question can't tell that $A$ and $B$ are integers, because that's merely a coincidence. If the original equation would have been $x^3 + Ax^2 + Bx + \pi^3$, $A$ and $B$ would have been $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ respectively.
